java 17 - Unable to make private java.io.File accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module
In my Maven Java application, I have a pom.xml file that internally triggers an Ant script, within which there is a Groovy script containing Java.io.File related implementations (given below).
<groovy>
  def file_dir = new File(properties["file_path"])
  def src_dir = new File(properties["source_dir"])
  def file_list = properties["file_list"]
  ant.echo(message:"Copying sources from " + src_dir)
  new File(file_list).eachLine() { line ->
    def file = new File(file_dir, line)
    ant.copy(todir:file_dir, file:file, overwrite:"true")
  }
</groovy>

After upgrading from Java 11 to Java 17, I encountered the following error during compilation:
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private java.io.File(java.lang.String,java.io.File) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @72f9f27c

I tried passing the --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED parameter through the pom.xml file, but the issue persists.
Any suggestions?
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <argLine>--add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED</argLine>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>

Full trace as requested:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (create-dist) on project snapshot: An Ant BuildException has occured: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[ERROR] D:\SourceCode\snapshot\src\main\scripts\build.xml:29: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[ERROR] D:\SourceCode\snapshot\src\main\scripts\build.xml:50: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private java.io.File(java.lang.String,java.io.File) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @72e295cc
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<ant dir="D:\SourceCode\snapshot\src/main/scripts">... @ 5:119 in D:\SourceCode\snapshot\target\antrun\build-main.xml
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (create-dist) on project snapshot: An Ant BuildException has occured: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\SourceCode\snapshot\src\main\scripts\build.xml:29: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\SourceCode\snapshot\src\main\scripts\build.xml:50: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private java.io.File(java.lang.String,java.io.File) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @72e295cc
around Ant part ...<ant dir="D:\SourceCode\snapshot/src/main/scripts">... @ 5:119 in D:\SourceCode\snapshot\target\antrun\build-main.xml
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An Ant BuildException has occured: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\SourceCode\snapshot\src\main\scripts\build.xml:29: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\SourceCode\snapshot\src\main\scripts\build.xml:50: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private java.io.File(java.lang.String,java.io.File) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @72e295cc
around Ant part ...<ant dir="D:\SourceCode\snapshot/src/main/scripts">... @ 5:119 in D:\SourceCode\snapshot\target\antrun\build-main.xml
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute (AntRunMojo.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\SourceCode\snapshot\src\main\scripts\build.xml:29: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\SourceCode\snapshot\src\main\scripts\build.xml:50: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private java.io.File(java.lang.String,java.io.File) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @72e295cc
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException (ProjectHelper.java:568)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute (Ant.java:443)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute (UnknownElement.java:292)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute (DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform (Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute (Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks (Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets (Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget (Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute (AntRunMojo.java:313)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\SourceCode\snapshot\src\main\scripts\build.xml:50: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private java.io.File(java.lang.String,java.io.File) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @72e295cc
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException (ProjectHelper.java:568)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute (Ant.java:443)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute (CallTarget.java:105)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute (UnknownElement.java:292)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute (DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform (Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute (Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks (Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets (Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets (SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets (Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute (Ant.java:441)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute (UnknownElement.java:292)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute (DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform (Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute (Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks (Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets (Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget (Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute (AntRunMojo.java:313)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private java.io.File(java.lang.String,java.io.File) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @72e295cc
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute (DispatchUtils.java:116)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform (Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute (Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks (Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets (Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets (SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets (Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute (Ant.java:441)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute (CallTarget.java:105)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute (UnknownElement.java:292)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute (DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform (Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute (Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks (Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets (Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets (SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets (Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute (Ant.java:441)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute (UnknownElement.java:292)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute (DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform (Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute (Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks (Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets (Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget (Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute (AntRunMojo.java:313)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private java.io.File(java.lang.String,java.io.File) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @72e295cc
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible (AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible (AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.checkCanSetAccessible (Constructor.java:188)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.setAccessible (Constructor.java:181)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.<init> (CachedConstructor.java:32)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass.getConstructors (CachedClass.java:237)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.<init> (MetaClassImpl.java:115)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry$MetaClassCreationHandle.createNormalMetaClass (MetaClassRegistry.java:102)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry$MetaClassCreationHandle.create (MetaClassRegistry.java:92)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.getGlobalMetaClass (MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:252)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.access$100 (MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl$LocallyKnownClasses.getFromGlobal (MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:112)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl$LocallyKnownClasses.getMetaClass (MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl$MyThreadLocal.getMetaClass (MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:361)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.getMetaClass (MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:265)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeConstructorOf (InvokerHelper.java:808)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeNewN (ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:230)
    at embedded_script_in_D__SourceCode_snapshot_src_main_scripts_build.run (embedded_script_in_D__SourceCode_snapshot_src_main_scripts_build.xml:2)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy.execGroovy (Groovy.java:350)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy.execute (Groovy.java:230)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute (UnknownElement.java:292)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke (Unknown Source)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute (DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform (Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute (Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks (Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets (Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets (SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets (Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute (Ant.java:441)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute (CallTarget.java:105)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute (UnknownElement.java:292)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute (DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform (Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute (Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks (Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets (Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets (SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets (Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute (Ant.java:441)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute (UnknownElement.java:292)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute (DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform (Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute (Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks (Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets (Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget (Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute (AntRunMojo.java:313)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)


Why do you use an Ant Script and Groovy ? What is the purpose of that?

The only two-args c'tor call in your example uses File, String (the public c'tor,
that should just be fine); so either there is another place, that swaps the
args/types like the error message suggests -- or the error ins not related to
your groovy script; could you please relate the stacktrace to the groovy code?
E.g. add the full trace or is something above/below it?

Which version of Groovy? Groovy uses internals of some java classes, the access to those internals has been restricted in newer Java versions and you must therefore adapt by using a current version of Groovy.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Thank you everyone for sharing your inputs.
@cfrick I have added full trace which to too big.

@ThomasKläger - we are using Groovy 2.4.15 version

According to the stacktrace:

Caused by: org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\SourceCode\snapshot\src\main\scripts\build.xml:29: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\SourceCode\snapshot\src\main\scripts\build.xml:50: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private java.io.File(java.lang.String,java.io.File) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @72e295cc


the problem is on line 50 of src\main\scripts\build.xml.
According to my analysis (Groovy tries to execute new File(String, File)) you might have your parameters swapped on that line, i.e. something like:
new File(line, file_dir)

instead of:
new File(file_dir, line)

I'm not sure whether it is from the code that you have included or whether it is from some other code.

Note that when using Java this would be a compile time error (because you cannot call a private constructor from outside its class), but Groovy tries to use that constructor anyway (and fails because Java 17 further restricts the access to JDK internals, an ongoing process since Java 9.)
